# I have a questions about Pasta sauce spoilage

Tags: sauce

After pouring a new  jar of sauce, I noticed dried sauce around the rim of the cover. Is it still safe to use?

Comment: Hi Kathy, welcome to the forum.  You'll have to provide more information.  Dehydrated/dried sauce, in and of itself isn't necessarily unsafe, but a lot depends on storage situation and time.  So, the more detail you can add the better response you will receive.

Comment: you can [edit] your question to add more details; also check [ask] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points to look at:

- Was the air seal broken prior to use?
- What is the printed shelf-life (or best-by date) in comparison to the date of use?
- Are there any detectable (organoleptic) signs of spoilage?
- Has the product been stored accordingly as instructed on the label?

Pasta sauce is *typically* high-acidity, which makes it less prone to spoilage, especially when still within shelf-life / BBD.  This doesn't rule spoilage out completely, and as others have pointed out, more details would definitely help make a more accurate determination.  Strictly speaking, most food packaging do not have zero air permeability, so it wouldn't be unusual to see change in water activity.  If this were for a commercial/industrial application, you could always send it out for lab sampling (or do so in-house), but i'm presuming that isn't likely the case here?